# Cannot use radio transmitter after switching to LowPower library

Tags: power, sleep, arduino-mini

My Arduino Mini board has DHT22 temperature sensor and 433MHz radio transmitter modules. I'm using `DHT` and `RCswitch` libraries to make use of them. Code looks like this:

```
void setup() {
  tempSwitch.enableTransmit(RADIO_PIN);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  float temp = dht.readTemperature();

  unsigned long message = createTemperatureMessage(SENSOR_ID, temp);
  tempSwitch.send(message, 32);

#ifdef MY_DEBUG
  unsigned int sleepCount = 1; 
#else
  // 3600s / 2 / 8s == 225
  unsigned int sleepCount = 225;
#endif
  for (; sleepCount > 0; sleepCount--) {
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
  }
}
```

So I'm reading temperature and sending it using `RCswitch` library. Initially I just had `delay(1000);` instead of fancy `LowPower` sleep loop but I wanted to make my "device" more battery-friendly so I switched to low-power sleep.

The problem is that now Arduino is only sending data first time and after sleeping 30 minutes (in "release" mode) it does not send anything anymore. If I reduce 30 minutes to 8 seconds it is capable of sending data as well as if I replace sleep with `delay(30*60*1000);`.

From beyond it looks like something is not caching up after the sleep. Do I need to "wake" radio module in any special way? How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this, but if you are putting the Arduino to sleep I would expect it to cut power to the devices (does it?) if it does then after a 30 minute sleep I would expect the devices to come back up in the initial state.  Guessing by your code the initial state of the radio is Tx Disabled, so try moving the

```
tempSwitch.enableTransmit(RADIO_PIN);
```

to before the

```
float temp = dht.readTemperature();
```

line.

I'd also be concerned that the DHT22 is not in the correct state after you wake up.

Can you try doing a 1 second LowPower sleep in debug mode, I suspect it would work more often.

Comment: You idea kind of worked (I just called `setup()` instead) but with addition of `delay(1000);` after power-down sleep itself.